# what does this output of nvidia-smi mean

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have four GTX1080 and am doing deep learning. I typed `nvidia-smi` on the command line and got this output. Does this mean that all 4 GPUs are in use ? If so, how do I stop them ?

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3979      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           171MiB |
|    0      4589      G   compiz                                       173MiB |
|    0      5808      C   /usr/bin/python                              535MiB |
|    0     13072      C   python                                      3609MiB |
|    1     22390      C   python                                      5949MiB |
|    2      5804      C   /usr/bin/python                              535MiB |
|    3      5812      C   /usr/bin/python                              535MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

G means Graphics use, this is the usual. Software that uses OpenGL will likely be using the GPUs, often needing not much memory, so it generally can be left as it is.

C means compute. You have some Python scripts that are using the code for compute, with OpenCL or CUDA. You can stop them simply by closing the process, either normally, or you can kill it with root access (such as from `htop`)